# Flutter find Widget in List<Widget>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widgets:

```
List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();

widgetList.add(WidgetA());
widgetList.add(WidgetB());
widgetList.add(WidgetC());
widgetList.add(WidgetD());
```

Now I want to find WidgetB in the list:

```
Widget activeWidget = widgetList.firstWhere((x) => x.key == ??);
```

I'm assmuning the **"key"** property is what I should use to uniquely identify each widget but I'm not sure what type of key to use or how to find by the key, nor if this is the correct approach.

Any information would be helpful thanks.

Comment: In the constructor of `WidgetX`, you can simply pass `key`, and you can easily use `x.key` afterwards.

Comment: I Would really love to know your use case.  I'm curious.

Comment: @nonybrighto I have a drawer as a menu and I want to switch between different views without loosing the drawer nor calling it from different screens. Using provider, my model has a variable for the active Widget / Screen.

Comment: @elmer I don't think you should be storing widgets in provider. You can store the data it needs instead of the widget itself.

Comment: @nonybrighto Thanks, when I looked at Blasanka's answer I realized that I only need to create the Widget on the fly and keep data in the model as you suggested.

Comment: @elmer. You are welcome. That is the best way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the keys for each widget:

```dart
var keyA = UniqueKey();
var keyB = UniqueKey();
var keyC = UniqueKey();
var keyD = UniqueKey();
List<Widget> widgetList = List<Widget>();

widgetList.add(WidgetA(key: keyA));
widgetList.add(WidgetB(key: keyB));
widgetList.add(WidgetC(key: keyC));
widgetList.add(WidgetD(key: keyD));
```

And now you can search:

```dart
Widget activeWidget = widgetList.firstWhere((x) => x.key == keyB);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to **compare by only the `Widget` name/type** without considering anything else. This is also works:

```
List<Widget> widgetList = [];

widgetList.add(WidgetA());
widgetList.add(WidgetB());
widgetList.add(WidgetC());
widgetList.add(WidgetD());

// using runtimeType
List widgets = widgetList.where((element) => element.runtimeType == WidgetD().runtimeType).toList();
Widget activeWidget = widgets.length > 0 ? widgets.first : null;
print(activeWidget);

// firstWhere() is the shorter form of above(I mean not how firstWhere implementation)
Widget activeWidget = widgetList.firstWhere((element) => element.runtimeType == WidgetD().runtimeType);
print(activeWidget);
```

Also note that doc contains like this:

> ```
>   /// If the [runtimeType] and [key] properties of the two widgets are
>   /// [operator==], respectively, then the new widget replaces the old widget by
>   /// updating the underlying element (i.e., by calling [Element.update] with the
>   /// new widget). Otherwise, the old element is removed from the tree, the new
>   /// widget is inflated into an element, and the new element is inserted into the
>   /// tree.
> ```